# Generate big data in excel or pdf using REST API

Tags: excel, rest, pdf-generation, microservices

I'm trying to generate the excel report file in micro-service using REST API.
On REST API if the generation process may take long time, connection would give time out for the users.
Is there any best practice or architecture pattern for this purpose?
EX: If data includes 10 column with 1 million rows the generation process should spend 30 seconds. Also it might depends on what technical resources we have.

Answer (score 2):

You should do heavy task in asynchronous way. Client should just trigger the process and should not wait for the completion. Now question come how Client will get updated copy of Excel. There are 2 ways:-

1. In response of initiate call, server return a job Id. Client will keep polling for the status of job Id. Whenever job get completed, it will get the file.
2. Some notification mechanism like Socket.io, where server will notify whenever job is done. After getting notification, client may download the processed file.